# How do i create a role?

Tags: discord.js

I've tried using this, but it doesn't work, anyone have any idea of how to create a role using Discord.js?
[Code here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gftgh.png)

Comment: I suggest you paste your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let vRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Verified");
if (!vRole) {
 vRole = await message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: 'Verified', permissions: [], color: '#00ff22' } })
}
```

this could possible give a error saying `await is only valid in async function` so you gotta make the function async.

Info:
 - https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#creating-a-role-with-permissions
Changes: 
- https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#guild-createrole